# Select from table valued function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, user-defined-functions

Is it possible for a view to select columns from a table valued function ?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnGetLatestOrderStatus(@OrderId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT TOP (1) Status, TimestampUtc    
    FROM OrderStatusHistory
    ORDER BY TimestampUtc DESC
GO

CREATE VIEW MyView AS
SELECT  
    OrderId,
    CustomerId,
    fnGetLatestOrderStatus(OrderId).Status AS OrderStatus,
    fnGetLatestOrderStatus(OrderId).TimestampUtc AS OrderStatusTimestamp
FROM Orders
GO
```

SSMS doesn't like this with error

> Cannot find either column "fnGetLatestOrderStatus" or the user-defined function or aggregate "fnGetLatestOrderStatus", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
SELECT o.OrderId, o.CustomerId, flos.*
FROM Orders o CROSS APPLY
     dbo.fnGetLatestOrderStatus(o.OrderId int) flos;
```

You need to call the table-valued function in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible if you get the syntax right. Note:

1. Functions must be fully qualified including the schema name (which I have assumed is dbo).
2. You select from the function as per any normal query, as opposed to using object reference notation as you did.

```
    CREATE VIEW MyView
    AS
    SELECT  
      OrderId
      , CustomerId
      , (select Status from dbo.fnGetLatestOrderStatus(OrderId)) AS OrderStatus
      , (select TimestampUtc from dbo.fnGetLatestOrderStatus(OrderId)) AS OrderStatusTimestamp
    FROM Orders
    GO
```

NOTE: And Gordon's solution is probably a better fit to your problem, but I thought it worth pointing out the 2 mistakes for your reference

Comment: Do you say that @GordonLinoff solution is better because calling the function twice opens the door for the underlying data to be updated ?  In other words, it's not likely but possible that a view row could have a previous `OrderStatusHistory.Status` paired with a new `OrderStatusHistory.TimestampUtc` ?

Comment: @BaltoStar no, there is not any danger of receiving invalid data, just a slight performance decrease due to calling the function twice. The way Gordon has shown is how to make best use of an inline table valued function.